# SQL GROUP BY and HAVING issue

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm learning some sql and I'm doing some exercises to learn better and I'm having trouble with the GROUP BY function.
So I have a some basic Tables of Actors(Title, Year, CharacterName, Name) and Movies(Title, Year). My task is to list the Actors name who played more than one character in the same movie.
This is the code I tried:

```
SELECT A.Name
FROM Actors A, Movies M
WHERE A.Title = M.Title AND A.Year = M.Year
GROUP BY A.CharacterName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

However I get this error:

> error 1055(42000):Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'new.A.Name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clase; this is incompatible  with sql_mode = only_full_group_by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `movie` is uniquely identified by `title` and `year` and an "actor" is identified by `name` ... we don't necessarily need a join to the `movie` table.

We could identify an actor that appeared in the same movie with multiple `character_name` with a query like this:

```
SELECT a.title
     , a.year
     , a.name
  FROM actors a
 GROUP
    BY a.title
     , a.year
     , a.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.character_name) > 1
```

We can remove expressions from the SELECT list that we don't need. If only need the name of the actor

```
SELECT a.name
  FROM actors a
 GROUP
    BY a.title
     , a.year
     , a.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.character_name) > 1
```

Note that this has the potential to return the same actor name multiple times.

e.g. "Mike Myers" appeared as multiple characters in multiple movies in the "Austin Powers" series. The first query would list the movie along with the actor. This query just removes the movie info from the SELECT list, but would still leave "Mike Myers" multiple times, once for each movie.

If removing duplicates is part of the specification, the query could be tweaked.

---

If we need a join to the `movie` table, I'd recommend ditching the old school comma syntax for the join operation, and using the JOIN keyword instead. And also move the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause.

If we assume that the combination of `title` and `year` is a unique identifier for a `movie`, then something like this:

```
SELECT a.name
  FROM actors a
  JOIN movie m 
    ON m.title  = a.title
   AND m.year   = a.year 
 GROUP
    BY a.title
     , a.year
     , a.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.character_name) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

All columns which you have on select should be also under group by directive:

```
SELECT A.Name, Count(A.CharacteName) 
FROM Actors A, Movies M
WHERE A.Title = M.Title AND A.Year = M.Year
GROUP BY A.Name
HAVING COUNT(A.CharacteName)) > 1;
```

Comment: Oh i see , thank you for the help now it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to help!  If it was useful then please accept my answer as the answer (the checkmark below the answer).

Comment: This query works perfectly in that it returns a resultset... but the resultset it returns doesn't satisfy the specification given in the question... actors with "more than one role in the *same movie*".

Comment: Thank you @spencer7593, now i saw the details group also on Title and Year :)

Comment: This query will return the name of any actor that appears in any two (or more) movies. The only restriction in this query is that it would be different character name in those movies. For example, take "Robert Redford" appeared in "A Walk In The Woods" and "All Is Lost". That's two different character_name, in two different movies. This query would return "Robert Redford", but that return doesn't seem to fit the specification... different character_name in the ***same*** movie.